# Is there a component like highstock for react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Highstock doesn't seem to want to work with react native.  I keep getting the error "Invariant Violation: View config not found for name div.  Make sure to start component names with a capital letter." when following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@priya_jain/visualizing-the-data-in-react-using-charts-c7e72dc7523b

I stripped the div component out and made sure it was contained within a View, but I suspect the component is just not built for react native?? Is there a way around this, or a similar component I could use?  I'm mainly looking for the ability to let the users interact with the graph by picking dates and zooming in the way Highstock allows you to.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: I see there is a react-native port of the Highcharts library that is used by Highstock, see https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native - perhaps this may be sufficient for your use case? Also, normally speaking, React libraries are rarely compatible with React Native.

Comment: Hello!  Thank you for your reply.  I do have the graph working under that library, it works great.  The only issue is that there is no way for the user to select the date range, nor does it have the zoom bar on the bottom that highstock provides.  If it's not possible to use highstock itself, are there any graph libraries that are similar?  With the ability for the user to select dates and zoom in on the graph in real time.

Comment: I ended up finding the magic words that google wanted.  There was a unofficial component that required a little bit of updating but it allows highstock to work.  Thank you :)  For anyone interested:  I used https://github.com/TradingPal/react-native-highcharts#readme